# Collect LoC from SVN by java package

Tags: svn, diff

I wish to get a linecount on changes per package using SVN.

I.e. I want output of the form:

src.com.mypackage +155 !487 (+ = lines added, ! = lines modified)

M: Changed1.java

A: Added2.java

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `svn log` to get a list of changed files, or `svn diff --summarize` will return you a list of changed files.

To get a count of changed lines, you could parse the output of `svn diff`, or you could parse the output of `svn blame` if you specified 1 revision change (use the -c option to refer to a single revision)

In all cases, there's a --xml option to get something more easily parsable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use http://wiki.statsvn.org

A bigger question is why do it?  LoC is at best a  pretty dodgy metric.

Is your management asking for it?  I'd try to advise them how the metric doesn't really mean anything (in fact it could change developer behavior in a bad way to achieve 'success' by this metric).